# How do I access an enum in Swift from Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, enums, swift

There is a global enum defined in Objective-C:

```
typedef enum {
     UMSocialSnsTypeNone = 0,
     UMSocialSnsTypeQzone = 10,
     UMSocialSnsTypeSina = 11,                 //sina weibo
} UMSocialSnsType;
```

This code sets the sharetype of a platform:

```
snsPlatform.shareToType = UMSocialSnsTypeDouban;
```

In Swift, I want to get the sharetype of the platform:

```
var snstype = snsPlatform!.shareToType
println(snstype)
```

Result: `UMSocialSnsType (has 1 child)`

```
snstype.toRaw()
```

Error: `UMSocialSnsType does not have a member named "toRaw"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I can tell, `UMSocialSNSType` was declared in Objective-C without using the `NS_ENUM` macro, so it wasn't imported as a Swift `enum`. That means that instead of being able to use `.toRaw()` or `UMSocialSNSType.Douban` you have to use the different enumeration values as constant structs. Unfortunately the type also doesn't have the appropriate operators (`==` or `~=`) set up, so you have to compare the `value` property.

```
var snstype = snsPlatform!.shareToType

switch snstype.value {
case UMSocialSnsTypeDouban.value:
    println("douban")
case UMSocialSnsTypeEmail.value:
    println("email")
default:
    println("other")
}

if snstype.value == UMSocialSnsTypeDouban.value {
    println("douban")
}
```

The good news is that it looks like all the constants autocomplete in Xcode, so you should be able to do find the comparisons you need to do that way.

---

It looks like the Swift-version of the bridged `typedef...enum` must be something like:

```
struct UMSocialSnsType {
    var value:Int
    init(_ val:Int) {
        value = val
    }
}
let UMSocialSnsTypeNone  = UMSocialSnsType(0)
let UMSocialSnsTypeQzone = UMSocialSnsType(10)
let UMSocialSnsTypeSina  = UMSocialSnsType(11)
// etc
```

Whereas if it had been declared in Objective-C with the NS_ENUM macro, it would look like:

```
enum UMSocialSnsType: Int {
    case UMSocialSnsTypeNone = 0
    case UMSocialSnsTypeQzone = 10, UMSocialSnsTypeSina // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much！I don't know enum have a "value" property ago. Now I solve the problem!

Comment: Enum normally doesn't have a "value" property. This is a struct -- sort of a fake enum.

Comment: Swift think enum is struct because UMSocialSNSType was declared in Objective-C without using the NS_ENUM macro ?

Comment: Added a little more explanation so you could see the difference between this and the way Swift imports NS_ENUM enumerations.